# How can one disable right click on Asus UX303LN trackpad asus smart gesture

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, asus-laptop

I have an asus UX303LN and it has two methods to right click on the trackpad, the first is to use 2 fingers on the trackpad which I like and would like to keep. The second is to click in the bottom right of the trackpad (which I always do by mistake) and do not want to keep.

I found another post that shows how to remove the asus smartgesture software and replace it with an ElanTech driver, however the driver wont install on this particular laptop so i suspect the hardware is not elan.  The device shows as an HID compliant vendor defined device in the device manager.

Looking at the regsitry settings in software current user asus smartgesture, I see lots of boolean defines but nothing really that would apply to right clicking.

Does anyone know how to disable the single finger right click on this trackpad?

Thanks